# Users with the most questions posted on MSE

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know if one can see a classification of the users by the number of the questions they asked on MSE. It's just a curiosity!

Comment: [meta-tag:data-explorer] might be useful. You might check some of the queries found when googling for [top askers site:data.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=top+askers+site:data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/124506/top-askers) returns the list of top `100` users by the number of questions asked.

At the top of the list, with `3826` questions asked, we find unregistered/deleted users.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!